# Found Fatal error: While Transfering website One server to another Server

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

i have change my server & try to transfer Opencart Website from old Server to New Server but my side is not working in New Server
i found following Error
Fatal error: require_once()

> Warning: require_once(/home/haratist/public_html/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/haratistore/public_html/index.php on line 16
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/haratist/public_html/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php55/lib/php/php') in /home/haratistore/public_html/index.php on line 16

My domanin name is  http://haratistore.com/

Comment: Are you sure all the files have been copied? It sounds like the system/ directory might have been missed.

Comment: You should find an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021

Answer (score 0):

You obviously renamed your user on the new server and use absolute paths, because you can see  the `require`d path:

```
/home/haratist/public_html/system/
```

and the path where are your files:

```
/home/haratistore/public_html/
```

Do you see the difference? You need to replace `haratist` with `haratistore` in all your absolute paths in your project. Hopefully there will not be a lot of them.